# Oracle SQL: how to show only one max per group

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, max, greatest-n-per-group

Hi everyone first thanks for your time.
I have this data

Data:

[image: Data]

And I have to obtain the max values of everygroup, if there is one group that has two same max values like

```
A 40 23/56/1982
A 40 31/4/5521
```

Only show one of them.
Like this

[image: result]

Till now I've tried two ways and they work only if there is not any repeated max per group.

Oracle SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUB.GRUPO,SUBG.FECHA,SUBG.VALOR
FROM T2 SUBG
LEFT JOIN T2 SUB2
ON SUBG.GRUPO = SUB2.GRUPO AND SUBG.VALOR < SUB2.VALOR
WHERE SUB2.VALOR is NULL
ORDER BY GRUP
```

```
SELECT GRUPO, FECHA
FROM T2
WHERE VALOR IN (SELECT MAX(VALOR) FROM T2 GROUP BY GRUPO)
ORDER BY GRUPO
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
 select * from (select a.*, row_number() over(partition by GRUPO order by VALOR desc) rn
 from T2 a
) a where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the greatest date per group, aggregation is sufficient:

```
select 
    groupo, 
    max(fecha) fecha
from t2
group by groupo
```

If you want the corresponding `valor` as well, then, since you have just 3 columns in the resultset, this might be a good spot to use `keep`:

```
select 
    groupo, 
    max(fecha) fecha, 
    max(valor) keep(dense_rank last order by fecha) valor
from t2
group by groupo
```

Answer (score 0):

The more traditional way to do this is using a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct groupo, fecha, valor
from t2 t
where valor = (select max(valor)
               from t2
               where groupo = t.groupo);
```